# F# Same assembly giving different performance

Tags: .net, f#

I am trying to understand why code which generates the same assembly is having such different performance. I have a struct that I am using to wrap an array to ensure the use of Units of Measure. Units of Measure are erased at compile time so there should be no performance hit. Here is the struct.

```ml
[<Struct>]
type StructWrapper<[<Measure>] 'Measure, 'Value> =
    val Values : array<'Value>

    new (values: array<'Value>) =
        {
            Values = values
        }

    member this.Item
        with get (idx: int<'Measure>) =
            this.Values.[int idx]

    member this.Length = 
        LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure<'Measure> this.Values.Length
```

I then create a couple of test functions and use [Fasmi](https://github.com/d-edge/fasmi) to see what assembly is generated.

```ml
[<Measure>] type ItemIdx


let test1 (x: array<float>) =
    let mutable acc = 0.0
    let mutable idx = 0
    let len = x.Length

    while idx < len do
        acc <- acc + x[idx]
        idx <- idx + 1

    acc


let test2 (x: StructWrapper<ItemIdx, float>) =
    let mutable acc = 0.0
    let mutable idx = 0<ItemIdx>
    let len = x.Length

    while idx < len do
        acc <- acc + x[idx]
        idx <- idx + 1<ItemIdx>

    acc
```

When I look at the assembly for `test1` and `test2`, I get the same assembly.

```
;Arr.test1(Double[])
L0000: vzeroupper
L0003: vxorps xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
L0007: xor eax, eax
L0009: mov edx, [rcx+8]
L000c: cmp eax, edx
L000e: jge short L001e
L0010: movsxd r8, eax
L0013: vaddsd xmm0, xmm0, [rcx+r8*8+0x10]
L001a: inc eax
L001c: jmp short L000c
L001e: ret

;Arr.test2(StructWrapper`1<Double>)
L0000: vzeroupper
L0003: vxorps xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
L0007: xor eax, eax
L0009: mov edx, [rcx+8]
L000c: cmp eax, edx
L000e: jge short L001e
L0010: movsxd r8, eax
L0013: vaddsd xmm0, xmm0, [rcx+r8*8+0x10]
L001a: inc eax
L001c: jmp short L000c
L001e: ret
```

When I got to profile this though, I get wildly different result. I ran some benchmarks using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet). I would expect to get the same timing but I'm getting very different numbers.

Here are my tests

```ml
[<Measure>] type ItemIdx

let iterationCount = 1_000
let numberCount = 1_000_000

let rawArray = [|1.0 .. (float numberCount)|]

let structApproach =
    [|1.0 .. (float numberCount)|] 
    |> StructWrapper<ItemIdx, _>

type Benchmark () =

    [<Benchmark>]
    member _.RawArray () =
        let mutable result = 0.0
        let mutable idx = 0
        let len = rawArray.Length
        while idx < len do
            result <- result + rawArray.[idx]
            idx <- idx + 1
            
        result

    [<Benchmark>]
    member _.StructWrapper () =
        let mutable result = 0.0
        let mutable idx = 0<ItemIdx>
        let len = structApproach.Length
        while idx < len do
            result <- result + structApproach.[idx]
            idx <- idx + 1<ItemIdx>
            
        result
```

And my results

// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.22000
AMD Ryzen 9 3900X, 1 CPU, 24 logical and 12 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.100
[Host]     : .NET 6.0.0 (6.0.21.52210), X64 RyuJIT DEBUG
DefaultJob : .NET 6.0.0 (6.0.21.52210), X64 RyuJIT

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RawArray | 688.8 us | 1.77 us | 1.48 us |
| StructWrapper | 2,280.1 us | 24.34 us | 20.32 us |

Why am I getting such different timings?

There's also a repo where you can clone and see the approaches I've been looking at [here](https://github.com/matthewcrews/UnitsOfMeasureIndexArray).

Comment: Same question about optimizations.

Comment: I don't see these results on win11 with .NET 6 (both from VS release mode run or `dotnet run`). I see identical results. You should consider stuffing the generated data you iterate through in the benchmark object as well. If I leave it at the top-level module level I'll get a runtime error (yay top-level module initialization weirdness)

Comment: Oh, interesting, when I put them in the Benchmark object, it's the same. Why would that make such a difference?

Comment: Turns out benchmarkDotNet was running the tests using a DEBUG build? I haven't figured out why yet.